# Piwik: There are no commands defined in the “generate” namespace?

Tags: symfony, matomo

Everyone.

I want to create plugin as the introduction told. [Adding a new API module](http://developer.piwik.org/guides/expose-api-methods), but I got this error.

[image]

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure to enable development mode:
`./console development:enable`